# Structuring and styling Gulp Sass output

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass

Hi is there a way to change the `gulp-sass` settings so that the closing bracket is on it's own line?

Current CSS output:

```
body {
  width: 100%; }
```

What I want:

```
body {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All you need is this code:

```
gulp.task('sass', function(){
  return gulp.src('app/scss/styles.scss')
    .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'expanded'})) // Converts Sass to CSS with gulp-sass
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
});
```

You need to clarify that you want expanded style of output.
Here you can find information about  [different sass output styles](https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/06/15/different-sass-output-styles/)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [gulp-cssbeautify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-cssbeautify) after the sass compiler.

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('./scss/*.css')
       .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
       .pipe(cssbeautify())
       .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/'));
}
```

EDIT: It looks to me George H. his answer is more efficient, take a look below.